# Attribute reference does not work with inheritence

Tags: php, inheritance, reference

I'm stuck with a behaviour of PHP which I can't seem to understand.

```
class A {
    private $v;
    public function __construct(&$v)
    {
        $this->v = &$v;
    }

    public function setV($v) {
        $this->v = $v;
    }

    public function getV() {
        return $this->v;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function setV($v) {
        $this->v = $v;
    }
}

$v = '1';
$c = new A($v); // <= this will be replaced

echo $c->getV() . "\n";
$v = '2';
echo $c->getV() . "\n";
$c->setV('3');
echo $c->getV() . "\n";
echo $v . "\n";
```

Outputs

```
1
2
3
3
```

But when I replace the object creation with `$c = new B($v);` it outputs

```
1
2
2
2
```

I would expect the same output as before. Why is this? I use PHP 5.3 but probably update to try to fix this.

Comment: You should use 'protected' instead of 'private'.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks for the hint @koen. Anyway, this should issue an error message in my opinion.

Comment: Oh, actually it *does* issue an error message. I screwed my configuration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a class extends another parent class it can only use public and protected variables and functions from the parent class..
So this will print the same result ;

```
<?php

class A {
 private $v;
  public function __construct(&$v)
  {
    $this->v = &$v;
  }

  public function setV($v) {
    $this->v = $v;
  }

 public function getV() {
    return $this->v;
  }
}

class B extends A {
    public function setV($v) {
        parent::setV($v);
    }
}

$v = '1';
$c = new B($v); // <= this will be replaced

echo $c->getV() . "\n";
$v = '2';
echo $c->getV() . "\n";
$c->setV('3');
echo $c->getV() . "\n";
echo $v . "\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you use `$c = new B($v)` but class B has no constructor then why you pass the parameter `$v`. use parent's constructor and try :

```
class B extends A{
   public function __construct($v)
    {
       parent::_construct($v)
    }
}
```

then try with your replacement.

Comment: `B` inherits `A`'s constructor, so that is not necessary. koen already pointed out my problem.